# react-native fetch - request body - Unexpected EOF

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

in my react-native application, I'm trying to make fetch request with `body`. But, I get error message of `unexpected EOF`. Actually, the request is made, I mean I can see through backend logs that request is sent, whereas, right after the request, it shows error message.

Here is my `fetch` method.

```
var Url = "https://----------";
        return fetch(Url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'number': '11111111-'})
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log("SEND_SMS RESULT: ",responseJson);
            })
            .done();
```

here is the error screen I get.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it fails on this line: `response.json()`
Are you sure that your response is a valid JSON?

Try testing the response with Postman or add `.catch(e => console.log(e))` before `done();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Url = "https://----------";
    return fetch(Url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'number': '11111111-'})
    })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseJson) => {
             const resposeJson2 = responseJson.length ? JSON.parse(responseJson) : {};
            console.log("SEND_SMS RESULT: ",responseJson2);
        })
        .done();
```

*Your server is returning null instead of error and unfortunately response.json() cant operate on null response*
you can research briefly on it the keywords are "Handling null response from api"