# SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm pulling data from the database, but I'm getting SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF React Native error when pulling data. Where's the problem?

```
class App extends Component {

    fetch('http://..../tbl_menuler_tipsiparis.php')
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((responseJson) => {

         firebase.database().ref('/TBL_SIPARISLER/tip').set(responseJson);

              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code snippet. It lacks necessary information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native fetch - request body - Unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727831/react-native-fetch-request-body-unexpected-eof)

Answer (score 0):

learn [react State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html%5C)

for your code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchDataWithFetchAPI();
  }

  fetchDataWithFetchAPI = () => {
    fetch('http://..../tbl_menuler_tipsiparis.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        firebase.database().ref('/TBL_SIPARISLER/tip').set(responseJson);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{"SampleText"}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```