# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error Unexpected EOF

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native

I am the beginner of react native. I have a problem. I am trying to get data from an api on react native but i couldn't do this. There is a compiler error that SyntaxError:JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

var api_key = "***";
var api_secret = "***";

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true, dataSource: []}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://apitest.kuveytturk.com.tr/prep/v1/data/fecs', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'appkey': api_key,
        'accesskey': api_secret,
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data,

        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) =>  <Text>{item.region}, {item.lang}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Where am I making a mistake? I have been dealing with this problem for a long time, thanks for your help.

Comment: can you print this "response.json()" and post the result ?

Comment: Can you try your code without parsing to json. Your code already get you json data. comment or remove '.then((response) => response.json())' line

Comment: You can check in Postman that whether you are getting json in correct format. And in this line .then((response) => response.json()) you can print response before returning response.json()

Comment: @OnurGelmez it's done but now there is empty page. I cannot get data from api

Comment: can you log responseJson to show what your request returned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native fetch - request body - Unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727831/react-native-fetch-request-body-unexpected-eof)

Comment: I don't think we can declare this a duplicate until the question is answered.